# How to map a default LINQ expression in a generic class

Tags: c#, linq, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have a generic `Repo` class that exposes a database LINQ provider:

```
class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted
{
    IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return _queryable;
    }
}
```

(`IPersisted` is a simple marker interface for persisted objects).

Now... I would like to find an elegant way to inject a default LINQ expression for certain derived types of `IPersisted`. For example, for the following IPersisted implementation:

```
class Deletable : IPersisted
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `IQueryable<T> Get()` method to return `_queryable.Where(q => !q.IsDeleted)`, only when `T` is of type `Deletable`.

I thought about creating some type of dictionary map `IDictionary<Type, Expression>`, and doing a lookup on `typeof(T)` inside the `Get` method but I'm not sure that I'll be able to strongly type the expressions in this case.

*How can I inject a "default" LINQ expression into the `Get` method, based on the type of `T`?* I'd like to have an extensible, object oriented way of mapping types to default expressions.

Comment: I doubt you'll make anything perfectly strongly-typed, since in the C# type system you can't express a constraint "a mapping from `T` to something generic featuring `T`, for arbitrary values of `T`"

Comment: Sounds like your `Repo` should be derived from a base class rather than an interface.

Comment: What about intorducing IDeletable interface. Then you could check if T is oftype IDeletable and return your query the way you want it?

Comment: @Zaid, what is the type of expression here? Is it not going to be `Func<T, bool>` always?

Comment: @nawfal yes we can assume it will always be `Func<T, bool>`

Comment: @epitka it's fine to have the mapping at an interface level. But you'd still need to do a lookup and I'm not sure how to do that. Can you share a code sample?

Comment: @Khan the `Repo` is not derived from anything at all in this code sample. In fact, it only specifies a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) of `IPersisted`

Comment: something like typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDeletable)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each `IPersisted` type is going to have its own expression, I would make that a constraint on the part of `IPersisted`. So now you have some kind of polymorphism.

Something like?

```
interface IPersisted<T> where T: IPersisted<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> Predicate { get; }
}

class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted<T>, new()
{
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        var dummy = new T();
        return _queryable.Where(dummy.Predicate);
    }
}

class Deletable : IPersisted<Deletable>
{
    public Deletable()
    {

    }

    public Expression<Func<Deletable, bool>> Predicate
    {
        get { return x => !x.IsDeleted; }
    }

    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I think what you need here is some kind of static polymorphism, [but since C# doesnt offer that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062468/why-shouldnt-cor-net-allow-us-to-put-a-static-shared-method-inside-an-inter), you might need create a dummy instance for yourself, just to get the expression.

---

If you can't have a default constructor, then you can rely on `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(t)`. You can adjust your `Get` method like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> Get()
{
    var dummy = (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
    return _queryable.Where(dummy.Predicate);
}
```

Two things out of possibly many things to note about `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`:

1. [It will not initialize anything or run the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136272/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-an-class-without-running-any-code-from-t), but that shouldn't be a problem for us.
2. [It's relatively slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582259/fast-creation-of-objects-instead-of-activator-createinstancetype). Shouldn't be a big deal since you can cache the instances :) Something like:

   ```
   class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted<T>
   {
       //caching mechanism: this is run only once per instance; you can make it 
       //static if this shud be run only once the entire lifetime of application
       readonly T dummy = (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));

       public IQueryable<T> Get()
       {
           return _queryable.Where(dummy.Predicate);
       }
   }
   ```

---

If the exact expression is not important, then you can get rid of the object instantiation. Something like:

```
interface IPersisted<T> where T: IPersisted<T>
{
    Func<T, bool> Predicate { get; }
}

class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return _queryable.Where(x => x.Predicate(x));
    }
}

class Deletable : IPersisted<Deletable>
{
    public Func<Deletable, bool> Predicate
    {
        get { return x => !x.IsDeleted; }
    }
}
```

---

If preserving the original definition of `IPersisted` is important, then you can make it non-generic. Not sure if that would make it any less strongly-typed.

```
interface IPersisted
{
    Expression<Func<object, bool>> Predicate { get; }
}

class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted
{
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return _queryable.Where(dummy.Predicate);
    }
}

class Deletable : IPersisted
{
    public Expression<Func<object, bool>> Predicate
    {
        get { return x => !((Deletable)x).IsDeleted; }
    }
}
```

---

The above approach can be made more strongly typed by going for a method in `IPersisted` but need not be good enough a constraint:

```
interface IPersisted
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetPredicate<T>() where T : IPersisted;
}

class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted
{
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return _queryable.Where(dummy.GetPredicate<T>());
    }
}

class Deletable : IPersisted
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> IPersisted.GetPredicate<T>() //made it explicit
    {
        return x => ((Deletable)(object)x).IsDeleted;
    }
}
```

---

Note: Make the `Predicate` implementation explicit if it doesn't make sense outside the `Repo<T>` class.

Comment: This is useful. The only problem is that I have to introduce an empty constructor constraint, and I've created most of my `IPersisted` implementations without empty constructors in order to force initialization of required fields. Static polymorphism would be wonderful for this case.

Comment: @ZaidMasud another way of tackling is to bring in some kind of hacks, is performance important?

Comment: Well I suppose performance is always important :) But what kind of hacks did you have in mind? Are you thinking of something like using `Activator` with default constructor types?

Comment: @ZaidMasud, even for activator, you need a default constructor (and public). I will edit my answer :)

Comment: `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`... good one. Learned something new. Will try it out and if things work out I'll accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ZaidMasud Pls catch the edit. I made a terrible mistake by going after a dictionary mechanism which is all unwanted. A static variable per generic type itself acts a cache. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686630/static-generic-class-as-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we're 100% on the same page but this get method example will take a linq Func which you can use as a where clause to filter your query.

```
class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted
{
    IQueryable<T> Get(Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        return _queryable.Where(filter);
    }
}
```

Edit: Not sure if this will translate well to sql but to make sure i have the right idea of what you want (and maybe spark a light) : Have you considered something like this?

```
class Repo<T> where T : IPersisted
{
    IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        if (typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IDeletable)))
        {
            return _queryable.Where(o => ((IDeletable) o).Deleted = false).AsQueryable();
        }
        return _queryable;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I was to go this route the usage would become something like `Get(q => !q.IsDeleted)` and I'd rather just keep it as is and say `Get().Where(q => !q.IsDeleted)`. The point here is for the `Get` method to automatically inject the expression based on the type, without the consumer getting involved.

Comment: Regarding your edit... yes this is exactly the type of thing I need, but in a more extensible manner as I want to have these expressions for multiple interfaces in addition to `IDeletable`. I'd rather not do it using a long list of `if` statements if I can avoid it.

Comment: Have you considered a strategy pattern where you hold a list of say IFilters. Each filter has 2 methods : bool DoesFilterApplyForType(Type) and another method to actually apply the filter if the first method returned true. You could inject the list of IFilters using dependency injection if you want.